# JSON parse error: window.onload vs XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm unable to parse a simple JSON-Object returned by PHP after an AJAX-`XMLHttpRequest()`. Here is the bizarreness in a nutshell (using a simple json for a test):

On page loads, if PHP sends:

```
<script>window.onload=function(){JSON2HTML({htm:{world {innerHTML:"hello!"}}});}</script>
```

my little JSON2HTML function recognizes typeof object and parses the json without complaint.

However, if PHP returns the exact same JSON string (from same PHP variable) via `XMLHttpRequest()`

```
{htm:{world:{innerHTML:"hello!"}}}
```

and `onreadystatechange` calls `JSON2HTML` to process it then javascript invariably interprets it as typeof string rather than `typeof` object and the function fails.

I have set the php response header to `"Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8"`, stripped all non-ascii characters from the response string and have manipulated the json object in every way imaginable and always get the same result. I've also tried to `JSON.parse` the ajax string and get an "unexpected token" error.

Anyone know what could possibly be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String which happens to contain valid JSON is not the same thing that actual JavaScript object. Try `JSON.parse(your_response_string)` before converting into HTML. It probably will complain a bit about missing quotes, so make sure your response is 100% valid JSON like this:

```
{"htm":{"world":{"innerHTML":"hello!"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply xersiee,
I've tried running the string through JSON.parse and get an "unexpected token" error. I've also tried enclosing the keys in both single and double quotes, which doesn't make a difference.

Comment: So, it's still not valid JSON. What's the exact response from the server? Note that server is the one here to provide syntactically correct JSON.

Comment: The exact reply is just the json string as shown above, nothing more. I noticed php had padded the response with about 10 unknown invisible characters, five on each end, but I trim()ed them and still the parse error persisted. I tried some regex to strip all non-ascii characters and that didn't help either - the json is still invalid, then though it's perfectly valid on a page load.

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"htm":{"world":{"innerHTML":"hello!"}}}')` works perfectly. Force your server to produce valid JSON and that's it.

Comment: Well that's some special magic you've worked, thanks! I swear I tried that formulation a dozen times with no benefit. And yet here it is working perfectly. Thanks very much!